# Shell comm parameters issue

Tags: linux, shell, comm

I have an issue running a shell script with parameters.
This command running directly on Linux works:

```
comm -13 <(sort /tmp/f1.txt) <(sort /tmp/f2.txt) > /tmp/f3.txt
```

If I am trying to run this shell script with this command sending the parameters and I am getting the error below:

```
test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'est.sh: line 6: `comm -13 <(sort $1) <(sort $2) > $3
```

Here is my shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash
comm -13 <(sort $1) <(sort $2) > $3
```

I run it with the following command:

```
sh test.sh /tmp/f1.txt /tmp/f2.txt /tmp/f3.txt
```

I have ran out of ideas what might be wrong.
Please assist.

Thank you,
-Andrey

Comment: `sh` is not `bash` `<(...)` is a bash feature. Don't use `sh` to run the script. Use `bash`.

Comment: The reason probably is that whatever `sh` on your system means it doesn't support [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution). Why did you put `#!/bin/bash` in your script and use `sh` to execute it? See this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Since you have specified `bash` in the script's `shebang`, why do you call it with `sh`? Simply run `./test.sh /tmp/f1.txt /tmp/f2.txt /tmp/f3.txt`
2. Use `bash` explicitly: `bash test.sh /tmp/f1.txt /tmp/f2.txt /tmp/f3.txt`